# Modify json file with gulp

Tags: json, node.js, gulp

I have a package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "author": "Company",
    "description": "A sample project.",
    "private": true
}
```

and I want to be able to update the version field using gulp.  I will set it to the build number from Jenkins using environment variables:

```
var version = process.env.MAJOR +'.' + process.env.MINOR + '.' + process.env.BUILD_NUMBER;
```

I would like a task that updates the version field of the json file to the value of version:

```
gulp.task('update-package-build-no', function () {
    pkg.version = version;
});
```

Any ideas?  Is this even achievable?  I will be reading my package.json file using angular to display the version number of the application on an about page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [gulp-bump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bump).

You can use the syntax:

```
gulp.src("package.json")
  .pipe(bump(process.env.MAJOR + '.' + process.env.MINOR + '.' + process.env.BUILD_NUMBER))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
```

By the way - it's major.minor.patch-tags+buildNumber. :-)

> Build metadata MAY be denoted by appending a plus sign and a series of
>   dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch or
>   pre-release version. Identifiers MUST comprise only ASCII
>   alphanumerics and hyphen [0-9A-Za-z-]. Identifiers MUST NOT be empty.
>   Build metadata SHOULD be ignored when determining version precedence.
>   Thus two versions that differ only in the build metadata, have the
>   same precedence. Examples: 1.0.0-alpha+001, 1.0.0+20130313144700,
>   1.0.0-beta+exp.sha.5114f85.

Comment: Is that going to replace the entire contents of the json?  I just want to update the version field?

Comment: It will only modify the version field, but `package.json` will be overwritten by gulp when it is piped out, so you may find you have issues if you try and edit `package.json` with two gulp tasks at the same time if you don't use a library like `async`.

Comment: Can you explain how / why the version field will only be updated?  I don't see you targeting only the version field?  Or is that what the bump package targets?

Comment: `gulp.src` will pick up the contents of package.json. This is piped to the `bump` function. The `bump` function will presumably deserialize the JSON inside of `package.json` and then modify the version field. The result is then piped to `gulp.dest`, which in turn writes the file to `./package.json`. I did not write the bump library but that is the impression I get. You can [view the source code](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-bump/blob/master/index.js) and see that it, indeed, only targets `opts.version`.

Comment: Yeah I thought that's what it was doing.  All working.  thank you :)

Comment: worth mentioning by the way you can skip gulp altogther by doing `npm version major.minor.version+buildNumber`, but this will git tag your version if done in a repo.